# passing char buffer to functions and getting the size of the buffer

Tags: c, arrays, function, char

I have set the buffer to size 100.
I display the buffer in the main function where the buffer is declared.
However, when I pass the buffer to the function and get the sizeof '4',
I was thinking it should be 100, as that is the size of the buffer that I
created in main. 
    output:
    buffer size: 100
    sizeof(buffer): 4

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void load_buffer(char *buffer);

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    printf("buffer size: %d\n", sizeof(buffer));
    load_buffer(buffer);

    return 0;
}

void load_buffer(char *buffer)
{
    printf("sizeof(buffer): %d\n", sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Comment: In main() you explicitly declared an array, whilst in load_buffer() you declared a pointer. The difference is, in main() the compiler knows that buffer is an array, but in load_buffer() the compiler doesn't know whether buffer is from an array, or an allocated peace of memory in the heap, or a struct or whatever. The compiler only knows the memory address (thus a pointer), so sizeof() returns the size of the memory address, which is 4 bytes long (because it's a 32 bits machine, if it was a 64 bits machine, it would be 8 bytes long). Hope this helps to understand a bit more.

Comment: Instead of sizeof() function, use strlen(), then it returns the size of the pointer value.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are using the size of the pointer to the buffer (4 bytes), rather than the size of the buffer.

In C, you have to pass the size of the buffer separately, which is part of the reason buffer overruns happen so easily and frequently.

```
void load_buffer(char * buffer, size_t bufSize)
{    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 23):

The answers by Mitch Wheat and hhafez are completely right and to the point. I'm going to show some additional information which may prove useful sometimes.

Note that the same happens if you tell the compiler that you have an array of the right size

```
void load_buffer(char buffer[100]) {
    /* prints 4 too! */
    printf("sizeof(buffer): %d\n", sizeof(buffer));
}
```

An array as parameter is just declaring a pointer. The compiler automatically changes that to `char *name` even if it was declared as `char name[N]`.

If you want to force callers to pass an array of size 100 only, you can accept the address of the array (and the type of that) instead:

```
void load_buffer(char (*buffer)[100]) {
    /* prints 100 */
    printf("sizeof(buffer): %d\n", sizeof(*buffer));
}
```

It's a pointer to the array you have in main, so you need to dereference in the function to get the array. Indexing then is done by

```
buffer[0][N] or (*buffer)[N]
```

Nobody I know is doing that and I'm neither doing it myself, because it rather complicates passing of the argument. But it's good to know about it. You can call the function like this then

```
load_buffer(&buffer)
```

If you want to accept other sizes too, i would go with the passing-N option the other two answers recommend.

Answer (score 8):

From the OP

> ```
> void load_buffer(char *buffer)
> {
>     printf("sizeof(buffer): %d\n", sizeof(buffer));
> }
> ```

Even though you can imagine that `load_buffer()` is passed the `buffer` by refrence, what is really happening is you are passing a pointer to `char` by **value.** The actual array is not passed so there is no way for the `load_buffer()` function to know the size of the buffer array

So what is `sizeof(buffer)` doing? It is simply returning the size of a pointer to char. If `load_buffer()` needs the size of the `buffer` it needs to be passed speratly.

Or you can create a new struct that contains both a char array and the size of the array, and pass a pointer to that struct instead, that way the buffer and it's size are always together ;)

Answer (score 4):

What happens, is when you pass an array to a function, you only pass the address of the array in the memory, not the size of the array.  What sizeof(buffer) is outputting in load_buffer() is the size of the pointer, which is four bytes.

The best way to keep the size of the buffer in the function is to change the function to:

```
void load_buffer(char *buffer, int length);
```

and the call to:

```
load_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

and then use length whenever you want the size of buffer.